# Adjust Intercept of Spark DataFrame API Logistic Regression Model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm training a logistic regression in Spark. However, due to specifics in my training data, I need to manually adjust the model afterwards, namely change the intercept.

That was easy to do with the RDD api - just instantiate a new LogisticRegressionModel:

```
val intercept = model.intercept() + adjustment
val model = new LogisticRegressionModel(model.weights(), intercept)
```

However, the LogisticRegressionModel constructor in the DataFrame API was made private. How can I make manual adjustments to the model?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this afternoon and I was in test mode, trying to make it happen no matter what, so I don't care how dirty it is: get the coefficients from your model, get the intercept, adjust it, then do your predictions by hand with the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.2/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala) they use in Spark (look for `BLAS.dot`, `margin` and `score`). At some point they use `BLAS.dot`, well `BLAS` is private to spark. Again do the same, retrieve the code for `dot`, deal with `SparseVector`/`DenseVector` and you can make it. Dirty but it works.

Comment: Or you could fork Spark and add your own copy function with a parameter that can shift the intercept. That works too. Probably more beautiful.

Comment: Apparently, it can be done more easily (still dirty) with reflection:

`val modelClass = classOf[LogisticRegressionModel];
val const = modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[Vector], classOf[Double]);
val intercept = trained.intercept - adjustment;
val newModel = const.newInstance(trained.uid, trained.coefficients, intercept:java.lang.Double))`